# Why Is the Observable Irrelevant to the Component Data Binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, components

I have confirmed that this component observable, which is loaded using RequireJS, changes as expected in the method, `showProductCode`, but on the view there seems to be a problem. Clicking the Sort Columns button does trigger the appropriate code and the KO observable does set the value to true, but no visible change happens. I never get to see the Close button. Am I binding incorrectly? Should I use an instance of `ColumnSortingViewModel` in place of the constructor itself?

EDIT: After viewing the text of the databound property, `ColumnSortingViewModel`, and the rest I realize that the problem may have something to do with creating the observable as opposed to referencing observables, as I do for `bIsReady`. `text: ColumnSortingViewModel` is shown as the function not the product of the function, which is `false`. `text: bIsReady` is shown to be `true` in contrast.

```
 define(['Scripts/knockout-3.4.0', 'text!./ColumnSorting.html'], function (ko, htmlString) {
            function ColumnSortingViewModel(params) {
                // Set up properties, etc.
                if (typeof params.sProductCode === 'function') this.sProductCode = params.sProductCode();
                else if (typeof params.sProductCode === 'string') this.sProductCode = params.sProductCode;

                this.bIsReady = params.bIsReady();
                this.aColumns = params.aColumns();
                this.bShowingColumnSortMenu = ko.observable(false);
            }

            // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
            ColumnSortingViewModel.prototype.hideProductCode = function _hideProductCode() {
                this.bShowingColumnSortMenu(false);
            };
            ColumnSortingViewModel.prototype.showProductCode = function _showProductCode() {
                this.bShowingColumnSortMenu(true);
            };

            // Return component definition
            return { viewModel: ColumnSortingViewModel, template: htmlString };
        });

    <div class="splitColumns" data-bind="css: sProductCode">
    <a class="button" data-bind="click: showProductCode ">Sort Columns</a>

<div data-bind="text: bShowingColumnSortMenu"></div> <!-- this show the observable function itself, "function c(..." -->
<div data-bind="text: bShowingColumnSortMenu()"></div> <!-- this shows the intended value, "false" -->
<div data-bind="text: bIsReady"></div>
</div>

<div class="splitColumns" data-bind="css: sProductCode">
    <a class="button" data-bind="click: showProductCode ">Sort Columns</a>
</div>

<!--ko if: bShowingColumnSortMenu()-->
<div class="regular" data-bind="css: sProductCode">
    <a class="button" data-bind="click: hideProductCode ">Close</a>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: This looks fine to me, as a sanity check I would debug out bShowingColumnSortMenu in the view - <p data-bind="value: bSho..." just to be certain its not $parent.bShowingColumnSortMenu or something similiar.

Comment: @dmoo All the properties work as expected (except `bShowingColumnSortMenu`) if I don't use ko. I can and do, for instance, set `bIsReady` to a ko observable.

Comment: I removed `Scripts/knockout-3.4.0` and `ko` in the component code and now it works as expected, but why?